# Finding values between!

Tags: java

I have set some constants.

```
public final double TWO = 50;
public final double ONE = 5;
```

I have a number

this.number

I want to check if the number is between ONE and TWO.

I got

```
if (this.number > ONE )
```

I cant work out how to check if its between though.
Cheers

Comment: and what I got for you is put "&& this.number < TWO" after the first check in the if condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, simply:

```
if (ONE < number && number < TWO)
```

or if you want to always put the variable on the left:

```
if (number > ONE && number < TWO)
```

Obviously you may want to use `>=` or `<=` to open/close the range, for example a lower-bound-inclusive, upper-bound-exclusive:

```
if (number >= ONE && number < TWO)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the logical and operator `&&` as:

```
if (ONE < this.number && this.number < TWO)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tons of code examples here, while they might help you with this problem, they won't help you at all with your next one, so instead of asking Java questiona all day long, you should probably check out the official tutorials on variables and operators :)

[Java: Variables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)
[Java: Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)
[Java: Summary of Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Feel free to read the rest of the tutorials, since learning how to help yourself with the aid of documentation is an important part of programming.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `&&` (and) operator:

```
if (this.number > ONE && this.number < TWO) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the simplest:

`if (this.number > ONE && this.number < TWO)`

There are also other logic operators and you should read about them in a book, documentation or a tutorial.